# Message precedence with parenthesis and how to check for it?

Tags: pharo

In the AST I'm looking at RBMessageNode and I'd like to check if that node as precedence that differs from the standard. Noticed startWithParenthesis and stopWithParenthesis but they don't seem to produce the results I expected.

```
aNode startWithParenthesis ifTrue: [ ... do whatever ... ].
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `start/stopWithoutParentheses`? They respond with the character index of both ends of the message source code (not with `true` or `false`.)

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is `#needsParenthesis`, which responds with `true` if the node has greater precedence that its enclosing node (or parent).

Comment: Works... added an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's interesting here is the equivalence between the original condition

- *detect nodes with a precedence that differs from the standard*

and the one the parser needs to conform to the Smalltalk syntax

- *the need for parenthesis*.

As a good practice, when one finds these kinds of coincidences it is good to make them explicit by adding a second selector that conveys the other meaning. Given that in this case these are methods for testing, we have two options:

**negative testing**:

```
subvertsPrecedence
  ^self needsParenthesis
```

**positive testing**:

```
hasStandardPrecedence
  ^self needsParenthesis not
```

We should implemente the one that better express our intention. And if we decide to implement the two of them, it is better to re-writte the second as

**positive testing**:

```
hasStandardPrecedence
  ^self subvertsPrecedence not
```

in order to make it clearer the relationship with the other.

Answer (score 1):

As per Leandro's suggestion the `needsParanthesis` selector can be used for this purpose:

```
aNode needsParenthesis ifFalse: [ ... do something ... ].
```

Good catch!